# Replacing missing value when web scraping (rvest)

Tags: r, dataframe, rvest

I'm trying to write a script that will go through a list of players provided by the website Transfermarkt and gathering some information about them. For that, I've created the script below, but faced a problem with 1 of the 29 players in the [list](http://www.transfermarkt.de/fc-bayern-munchen/leistungsdaten/verein/27/reldata/%262016/plus/1). Due to one page being arranged differently than the others, the code outputs a list of only 28 players since it can't find information on the aforementioned page.

I understand why the code I've written doesn't find any information on the given page and thus giving me a list of 28, but I don't know how to rewrite a code in order to achieve what I want:
for the script to simply replace the entry with a "-" if it does not find anything, in this case a nationality, for the node on a particular page and return a full list with 29 players with all the other info in it.

The player page in question is [this](http://www.transfermarkt.de/marco-friedl/profil/spieler/156990) and while the other pages has the node used in the code for nationality, here it's ".dataValue span".

I'm still quite new to R and it might be an easy fix, but atm I can't figure it out. Any help or advise is appreciated.

```
URL <- "http://www.transfermarkt.de/fc-bayern-munchen/leistungsdaten/verein/27/reldata/%262016/plus/1"
WS <- read_html(URL)

Team <- WS %>% html_nodes(".spielprofil_tooltip") %>% html_attr("href") %>% as.character()
Team <- paste0("http://www.transfermarkt.de",Team)

Catcher <- data.frame(Name=character(),Nat=character(),Vertrag=character())

for (i in Team) {
   WS1 <- read_html(i)
   Name <- WS1 %>% html_nodes("h1") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
   Nat <- WS1 %>% html_nodes(".hide-for-small+ p .dataValue span") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
   Vertrag <- WS1 %>% html_nodes(".dataValue:nth-child(9)") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()

   if (length(Nat) > 0) {
   temp <- data.frame(Name,Nat,Vertrag)
   Catcher <- rbind(Catcher,temp)
   }
   else {}

cat("*")
}

num_Rows <- nrow(Catcher)
odd_indexes <- seq(1,num_Rows,2)
Catcher <- data.frame(Catcher[odd_indexes,])
```

Answer (score 2):

It's honestly easier to scrape the whole table, just in case things move around. I find `purrr` is a helpful complement for `rvest`, allowing you to iterate over URLs and node lists and easily coerce results to data.frames:

```r
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

# build dynamically if you like
urls <- c(boateng = 'http://www.transfermarkt.de/jerome-boateng/profil/spieler/26485',
          friedl = 'http://www.transfermarkt.de/marco-friedl/profil/spieler/156990')

# scrape once, parse iteratively
html <- urls %>% map(read_html) 

df <- html %>% 
    map(html_nodes, '.dataDaten p') %>% 
    map_df(map_df, 
           ~list(
               variable = .x %>% html_node('.dataItem') %>% html_text(trim = TRUE), 
               value = .x %>% html_node('.dataValue') %>% html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% gsub('\\s+', ' ', .)
           ), 
           .id = 'player')

df
#> # A tibble: 17 × 3
#>     player              variable              value
#>      <chr>                 <chr>              <chr>
#> 1  boateng           Geb./Alter:    03.09.1988 (28)
#> 2  boateng           Geburtsort:             Berlin
#> 3  boateng         Nationalität:        Deutschland
#> 4  boateng                Größe:             1,92 m
#> 5  boateng             Position:   Innenverteidiger
#> 6  boateng          Vertrag bis:         30.06.2021
#> 7  boateng              Berater:         SAM SPORTS
#> 8  boateng      Nationalspieler:        Deutschland
#> 9  boateng    Länderspiele/Tore:               67/1
#> 10  friedl           Geb./Alter:    16.03.1998 (19)
#> 11  friedl         Nationalität:         Österreich
#> 12  friedl                Größe:             1,87 m
#> 13  friedl             Position: Linker Verteidiger
#> 14  friedl          Vertrag bis:         30.06.2021
#> 15  friedl              Berater:              acta7
#> 16  friedl Akt. Nationalspieler:     Österreich U19
#> 17  friedl    Länderspiele/Tore:                6/0
```

Alternately, that particular piece of data is in three places on those pages, so if one is inconsistent there's a chance the others are better. Or grab them from the table with the whole team—countries are not printed, but they're in the `title` attribute of the flag images, which can be grabbed with `html_attr`:

```r
html <- read_html('http://www.transfermarkt.de/fc-bayern-munchen/leistungsdaten/verein/27/reldata/%262016/plus/1')

team <- html %>% 
    html_nodes('tr.odd, tr.even') %>% 
    map_df(~list(player = .x %>% html_node('a.spielprofil_tooltip') %>% html_text(), 
                 nationality = .x %>% html_nodes('img.flaggenrahmen') %>% html_attr('title') %>% toString()))

team
#> # A tibble: 29 × 2
#>            player            nationality
#>             <chr>                  <chr>
#> 1    Manuel Neuer            Deutschland
#> 2    Sven Ulreich            Deutschland
#> 3      Tom Starke            Deutschland
#> 4  Jérôme Boateng            Deutschland
#> 5     David Alaba             Österreich
#> 6    Mats Hummels            Deutschland
#> 7   Javi Martínez                Spanien
#> 8     Juan Bernat                Spanien
#> 9    Philipp Lahm            Deutschland
#> 10        Rafinha Brasilien, Deutschland
#> # ... with 19 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will definitely look in to Purrr soon, but for now I just made an easy fix with a "if" statement.

Comment: At a minimum, try using `lapply` (the base equivalent of `purrr::map`) instead of a `for` loop; you'll find it's a much more useful structure that's used everywhere in R.